# PDFlib works only if the library is in /usr/lib not in a custom path

Tags: classpath, jboss5.x, java, pdflib

we are using [PDFlib](http://www.pdflib.com) for personalizing PDFs.

The *pdflib.jar* library and the libpdf_java.so  file are both in the folder:

```
/home/user/my/custom/library/path/
```

I start the server with this argument:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/home/user/my/custom/library/path/
```

like it is mentioned in the [pdflib tutorial](http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-8.0.3-tutorial.pdf)

After deploying on my jBoss5 Server i got this error message:

> ERROR [STDERR] Cannot load the PDFlib shared library/DLL for Java. 
>   Make sure to properly install the native PDFlib library.  For your
>   information, the current value of java.library.path is:
>   /home/user/my/custom/library/path/

So, the path ist correct (i tried it with and without the / at the end)

If I put the jar and the lib in my /usr/lib folder, everything works fine, but not with my custom folders.

I use it on a linux 64bit, if that matters!
The custom folder and the files got chmod 755 - so this shouldn't be the problem

Looking forward to your hints!